# From where a user came from to my facebook application

Tags: php, facebook

Is it possible to check from where user came to my facebook application? I'm looking for something similar to `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`. My facebook application is written in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

No, since facebook "proxies" every request to your app, you will never see a referer.
The only thing you could do would be handing out self generated referer-urls.

Just apply the GET parameter app_data to your url - this gets passed directly through to your app with the signed request.
This would be a method of tracking how many visitors come from sources you know and made a link deal, for example.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I've found something like this, but havn't understand how can I use it. It need to be in array:          $facebook->getSignedRequest(). But if I use link  - http://apps.facebook.com/MYAPP/?app_data=someinfo  I don't see it there.